# How to persist a map inside a map in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

So I have a class similar to this

```
public class MyClass{ 
...

@ElementCollection
private Map<Long,Map<Long,Double>> Vs = new HashMap<Long, Map<Long,Double>>(); 

...
}
```

This returns an error when I try to persist the class:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: MyClass_Vs, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(Vs)]
```

I think the error is because there is a map inside the original map that has the annotation of `@ElementCollection`. Any idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt Hibernate will be able to handle this type of mapping for you with just `@ElementCollection`.  You probably will need to define a new composite key, containing both of those `Long` map keys as `@Id` fields, then use an element collection on a `Map<CompositeLong, Double>`.  Granted, I'm making some assumptions about what those `Long` values represent, but it's hard to tell without more context.